# How to resolve AWS problem route not found Nginx Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nginx, thin

I'm trying to install my Ruby API on an AWS server, with nginx. 
And I have a problem that nginx can't find some of my roads (which works very well locally).

But it finds the one that are present on the address_server/v1/test path, but not the one present on address_server/test.

Does anyone have any idea where this might come from?

Thank you for taking some of your time!

Route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
  post 'user_fb_token' => 'user_fb_token#fb_create'

  namespace :api_v1, path: :v1, defaults: { format: :json } do
    DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS = {only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy], defaults: { format: :json }}.freeze

    post 'dislike', to: 'likes#delete', defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :likes, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update]

    post 'unwish', to: 'wishes#delete', defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :wishes, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS

    resources :notes, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS

    get 'products/wished', to: 'products#wished', defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :products, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS

    resources :categories, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS
    resources :happies, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS
    get 'selfies/liked', to: 'selfies#liked', defaults: { format: :json }
    get 'selfies/me', to: 'selfies#show_me', defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :selfies, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS
    get 'selfies/:id/fb_share', to: 'selfies#fb_share', defaults: { format: :json }

    get 'users/notify', to: 'users#notify_me', defaults: {format: :json}
    get 'users/me', to: 'users#show_me', defaults: { format: :json } 
    put 'users/me', to: 'users#update_me', defaults: { format: :json } 
    resources :users, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS
    get 'users/:id/request_friends', to: 'users#request_friends', defaults: { format: :json }
    get 'users/request_friends_callback', to: 'users#request_friends_callback', defaults: { format: :json }
    post 'users/:id/register_device', to: 'users#register_device', defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :reports, DEFAULT_API_V1_OPTS
  end
end
```

nginx config :

```
 upstream thin {
   server 127.0.0.1:3000;
 }

server {
  listen 80;
 server_name 52.47.133.83;

root /home/ubuntu/happer-api/public;

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
    rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
  }
  if (-f $request_filename.html) {
    rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
  }
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://thin;
    break;
  }
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
  root html;
}
}
```

Update

Backtrace from postman

```
Server →nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date →Wed, 22 May 2019 21:21:43 GMT
Content-Type →text/html
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Connection →keep-alive
X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
Cache-Control →no-cache
X-Request-Id →a65170fb-21e9-4e21-932a-f1ef554c94c3
X-Runtime →0.079642
Content-Encoding →gzip
```

nginx error log :

```
2019/05/23 10:48:29 [error] 15887#15887: *34 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 109.210.187.167, server: 52.47.133.83, request: "POST /user_token HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/user_token", host: "52.47.133.83"
```

Comment: can you post the backtrace errors when you try to hit the routes without the api namespace?

Comment: i updated my post